# Ambiguous behavior of while() loop in c

Tags: c

Since while loop terminates its execution for false expression, despite following are giving different outputs. Unable to trace

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    //code snippet 1
    while(0){
        ;
    }
    printf("C");
    return 0;
}
```

*this gives output*

```
c
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        //code snippet 2
        while(printf("%d")){
            ;
        }
        printf("c");
        return 0;
    }
```

*this gives output*

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Since printf() function returns the number of characters printed, and no character is being printed, therefore it should not result in an infinite loop as 0 has the logical value false.

Comment: It's not returning `0`. Try running `printf("%d", printf("%d"));`

Comment: You can refer to the behaviour of printf without variable name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437816/behaviour-of-printf-when-printing-a-d-without-supplying-variable-name

Comment: is the output compiler dependent. I am using minGW on windows

Comment: thanks, RishikeshRaje sshashank124, actually it is using some garbage value

Comment: What do you mean, no character is being printed? It's obviously printing the character `0` over and over! Which call do you think is printing `0`? It's not the second one, that prints `c`.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of your printf("%d") is not 0 (actually is a undefined behaviour).
See [Printf with no arguments explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660586/printf-with-no-arguments-explanation/27660628)